# iOS: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UIImage:drawInRect with 2 Images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

*I know that there are lots of questions to this topic here at StackOverflow, and i tried out many hints and answers hopefully. But nothing helped in this very plain and easy case.*

--

In an ARC-based Application I use a UIView subclass called SpeechBubbleView from Ray Wunderlich. It subclasses a UIView and was made to draw a speech bubble containing text like in an SMS-Message-App.

It uses two instances of an UIImage. In the drawRect-Method of the View the bubbles where drawn.

In the iPhone-Simulator everything works fine. But **on the iPhone 5** running iOS 7.1 there occure always an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception** every time the **second Image** is drawn, regardless if the first image was drawn or not.

I will provide some Code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* lefthandImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* righthandImage;
```

At the initWithFrame-Method both images where loaded from the supported files folder:

```
self.lefthandImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleLefthand"]
                      stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:19];

self.righthandImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleRighthand"]
                  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:19];
```

In the drawRect-Method of the SpeechBubbleView the images are drawn:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    CGRect bubbleRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, VertPadding, HorzPadding);

    CGRect textRect;
    textRect.origin.y = bubbleRect.origin.y + TextTopMargin;
    textRect.size.width = bubbleRect.size.width - TextLeftMargin - TextRightMargin;
    textRect.size.height = bubbleRect.size.height - TextTopMargin - TextBottomMargin;

    if (_bubbleType == BubbleTypeLefthand)
    {
        [self.lefthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
        textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextLeftMargin;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.righthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
        textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextRightMargin;
    }


    [[UIColor blackColor] set];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    textStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    [_text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:textStyle}];

}
```

At the code line, where the "RightHandImage" will be drawn, every time the BAD_ACCESS-Exception is thrown. If i comment this line out, everything works fine. The left-Hand-Bubble will be drawn perfectly as a "bubble".

Also, if i comment out the line where the first Image (left-Hand-Bubble) is drawn, the second Image will throw this exception.

Even if there is now multithreading implemented yet, i tried out to encapsulate the draw-Methods in **@synthesize(...){...}** following some hints here at StackOverflow to similar questions, but it was no solution and the Exception is still thrown every time.

I know that there is no other class holding an instance of this image to enter in access-rights-issues.

Can anyone give me some hints what to do here and now? Thank you!

**EDIT: UITableViewCell-Hint and creating really, own Image-Copies**

Maybe it's good to know that each Instance of the SpeechBubbleView is drawn in an reused UITableViewCell. Therefor, i do not use the UIImage-Instances returned by UIImage:imageNamed anymore, but create really copies of each using the following Code:

```
UIImage* tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleLefthand"];
self.lefthandImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[tmpImage CGImage] ]
                       stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:19];


tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleRighthand"];
self.righthandImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[tmpImage CGImage] ]
                       stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:19];
```

And, towards Putz1103 Suggestion, i added nil-guards around the draw-Methods:

```
if (_bubbleType == BubbleTypeLefthand)
{
    if(self.lefthandImage != nil) {
        [self.lefthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
    }
    textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextLeftMargin;
}
else
{
    if(self.righthandImage != nil) {
        [self.righthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
    }
    textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextRightMargin;
}
```

It still crashes on the iPhone, it only works in the iPhone-Simulator.

**EDIT 2: Something with the Rect to draw in**

It has something to do with the Rect. If i change the bubbleRect to a Rect starting at 0/0 with a width and height of 10 Pixel each, the Exception is **not thrown**.

If i use larger sizes of the rect the Exception occurs. So it seems that the Area is protected for something else

Comment: One possible implication is that `imageNamed:@"BubbleRighthand"` is failing (i.e. there is no such image)

Comment: @matt in such a case self.righthandImage should be nil, not? If it is nil problem line should not call exception.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. the UIImage-Instances are not nil. As already said, in the iPhone-Simulator it works perfectly. But also on the iPhone itself both images are present and nothing is nil.

Comment: It has something to do with the Rect. If i change the bubbleRect to a Rect starting at 0/0 with a width and height of 10 Pixel, the Exception is not thrown.

If i use larger sizes of the rect the Exception occurs. So it seems that the Area is locked for something else

Comment: What version of iOS are you running on your phone?  Depending on that you might be using the wrong `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` function.  Try doing the exact same thing with standard UIImages instead of stretchable ones.  I have a feeling that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the middle to

```
if (_bubbleType == BubbleTypeLefthand)
{
    if(self.lefthandImage != nil)
        [self.lefthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
    textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextLeftMargin;
}
else
{
    if(self.righthandImage != nil)
        [self.righthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
    textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextRightMargin;
}
```

Then see if it still crashes.  If it does not (it shouldn't) you know it's because the images failed to load for one reason or another.  Make sure the file names you are loading are **case correct to the ones you are including in your project** in the "Build Phases" section of the project properties.

Comment: nil is not an issue here. Both images are loaded pretty fine here. However, i added the nil-guard but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Please have a look at my second EDIT:

It has something to do with the Rect. If i change the bubbleRect to a Rect starting at 0/0 with a width and height of 10 Pixel each, the Exception is not thrown.

If i use larger sizes of the rect the Exception occurs. So it seems that the Area is protected for something else